# Substitute, replace string with perl

Tags: perl, plsql

I have string  like this:

`$string= "only this I need"`.

I am new in perl, and I tried to translate a PL/SQL code in perl.
My goal is to replace `"` with a blank space, finally it should look like this:

`$string = only this I need`

In PL/SQL I use this, and is working very well:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(string,'"','');
```

In perl I tried this, but is not working: `$string=~s/"/'';` receiving an error.

Please, help me, tell me what I need to read to do my job properly?

Comment: `$string =~ tr/"/ /;` (like `TRANSLATE( string1, chars_to_replace, replacement_chars )`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it should work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string= '"only this I need"';

print "$string \n"; #prints "only this I need"

$string =~ s/"/ /g;

print "$string \n"; #prints only this I need
```

Comment: It is removing all occurences of ' " ' into a single space. What else you need?

Comment: my fault, i forgot to write "/g"

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to remove quotes from string:

```
my $string= '"only this I need"';
$string =~ m/"([^"]*)"/;
print "$1\n";
```

In case if you know the first and last character is quotes, you can do this without using `regex`, just use `substr`:

```
my $string= '"only this I need"';
$string = substr $string, 1, -1;
print "$string\n";
```